# существует ли коллекция для выборки из arraylist только уникальных значений?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

гугл упрямо говорит что коллекции могут решить мою проблему,но какие ? и как их лучше применять молчит. может что-то подскажите новичку?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вам нужен LinkedHashSet он хранит уникальные значения в том порядке, в каком вы их добавляете

```
List<String> list=new ArrayList<>("a","a","b");
Set<String> set=new LinkedHashSet<>(list);
//внутри сета теперь ,"a","b"
```

Comment: есть три сэта. может быть стоит про них всех упомянуть?

Comment: С телефона неудобно(

Answer (score 2):

Существует. Например: пусть `integerArrayList` содержит (в частности) дубликаты, тогда `integerHashSet` будет содержать только уникальные значения из `integerArrayList`.

```
ArrayList<Integer> integerArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
HashSet<Integer> integerHashSet = new HashSet<>(integerArrayList);
```

Answer (score 1):

Если вы хотите, получить список уникальных элементов и вам важен исходный порядок вставки, то это делается следующим кодом:

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 1);
List<Integer> uniqueElements =
                 list
                    .stream()
                    .distinct()
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Если же, вы просто хотите получить колекцию уникальных элементов, то воспользуйтесь ответом  @post_zeew

Comment: D вопросе есть метка Андроид, а на нём нельзя юзать фичи из 8 явы

Comment: @ЮрийСПб я слышал, что можно https://medium.com/@nicopasso/java-8-stream-on-android-c629e4237d5f#.w1cbvrjui

Answer (score 0):

```
HashSet<String> data_resh_hashset = new HashSet <String>();
String[] data_resh;
```

помогло

Comment: стоило добавить пример: как именно эта коллекция решает твою задачу